# hibernate - MapKeyColumn excluded in insert

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have two Entity classes as follows in a sample application:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
  @MapKeyColumn(name="phone_type")
  private Map<String, Phone> phones = new HashMap<String, Phone>();

  public Map<String, Phone> getPhones() {
    return phones;
  }

  public void setPhones(Map<String, Phone> phones) {
    this.phones = phones;
  }
...
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
...
  @ManyToOne
  private Person owner;

  public Person getOwner() {
    return owner;
  }

  public void setOwner(Person owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
  }
...
}
```

Even though I've not included a field for phone_type in the Phone object, I'd want it to be persisted in the DB based on it's value in the Person classes HashMap.
I've not added the field to the Phone object to avoid managing data redundantly - as phone_type is already present as the key in the map.

When I try to persist a Person object I see that the hibernate runs inserts excluding the phone_type column - for example:

```
insert into person (first_name, last_name, id) values (?, ?, ?)

insert into phone (number, owner_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Am I missing something for this to work? As far as I can tell my example copies the one here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Map_Key_Columns_.28JPA_2.0.29 , yet I can't really get it to work.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Well, I got it to work, initially, by removing the `MapKeyColumn(name="phone_type")` annotation. With it, it was acting strange as described above. I put the `mappedBy="owner"` back in, and the phones_KEY (named phones_KEY by default without the `MapKeyColumn` annotation) is now in the `Phone` table.

```
create table Phone (id bigint not null, name varchar(255), owner_id bigint, phones_KEY varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

When I do an insert, it does two inserts first, without the phones_KEY and then an update for the phones_KEY field, presumably under one transaction.

```
insert into Person (name, id) values (?, ?)

insert into Phone (name, owner_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)

update Phone set phones_KEY=? where id=?
```

It seems to me that it (hibernate 4.3) shouldn't have a problem with naming the `phones_KEY` field to `phone_type`, but I guess it does. I don't know what to tell you about that.

UPDATE: I tried this and it solves the above problem of not being able to name the `phone_type` column. I don't know your table structure, but this generates the same table structure as your annotations above, which puts the `phone_Key` column in the `Phone` entity.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    ...
    @OneToMany( mappedBy="owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Phone> phones;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Phone {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Person owner;
    private String phone_type;
    ...
}
```

You'll notice that even though the `Entities` are different, the table structure created is the same. In this case, instead of putting `phone_type` as a `Map` key, and declaring the name with `MapKeyColumn`, it is put in the `Phone` entity as a field named `phone_type`. A OneToMany `List` is used instead of a map. Since the relation is specifically mapped by `owner`, neither Map or List affects the mapping. Now, the insert shows an insert of `phone_type` into the `Phone` table.

```
insert into Person (id) values (?)
insert into Phone (owner_id, phone_type, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the idea - in our production environment I'm not sure however if we'll be able to create additional tables.
So, a solution without creating a mapping table would be most helpful.